# R for loop to compute ratio of row means

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, rows, mean

I have a dataframe (df) like this:

```
Rif   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
a1   1   1   0   3   7   10  10  7   7   7 
b1   3   3   3   0   0   5   5   5   5   0
c1   1   3   0   0   2   3   3   3   3   3
```

I would need to compute a list of Vs as follows:

```
V1: mean(A5:A5)/mean(B5:B5)
V2: mean (A4:A5) / mean (B4:B5)
V3: mean (A3:A5) / mean (B3:B5)
....
```

I think I should use a for loop. I have tried the loop written below, but it doesn't work:

```
ref <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 dat1 <- NULL

 for (i in 2:length(ref)) {
   for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
     dat1[j] <- rowMeans(df[j,i-1:6])/rowMeans(df[j,i+6-1:11])
   }
   df[,paste0("V", i)] <- dat1
 }
```

The output I would expect is like this:

```
Rif   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
a1    1   1   0   3   7   10  10  7   7   7 
b1    3   3   3   0   0   5   5   5   5   0
c1    1   3   0   0   2   3   3   3   3   3
```

Comment: What language are you using? Please edit your tags to include that. And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I'm using R language

Comment: `i-1:6` is identical with `i-(1:6)`; you want `(i-1):6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing your steps, you can try:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  df[,paste0("V", i)] <- rowMeans(df[,(i+1):6,drop=FALSE])/rowMeans(df[,(i+6):11,drop=FALSE])
}
df
#  Rif A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
#1  a1  1  1  0  3  7 10 10  7  7  7 0.2926829 0.3548387 0.4761905 0.7142857 1.0000000
#2  b1  3  3  3  0  0  5  5  5  5  0 0.4500000 0.4000000 0.3000000 0.0000000       NaN
#3  c1  1  3  0  0  2  3  3  3  3  3 0.4000000 0.4166667 0.2222222 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

You can skip the `j` - loop, which was sub-setting per row and then using `rowMeans`. On the other hand `drop=FALSE` is needed for the case when you subset only one column. The indices are currently hard coded, but will work when the data structure stays the same.

Or you use `sapply` instead of the `for-loop` like:

```
ref <- 1:5
names(ref)  <- paste0("V", ref)
df <- cbind(df, sapply(ref, function(i) {rowMeans(df[,(i+1):6,drop=FALSE])/rowMeans(df[,(i+6):11,drop=FALSE])}))
df
#  Rif A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
#1  a1  1  1  0  3  7 10 10  7  7  7 0.2926829 0.3548387 0.4761905 0.7142857 1.0000000
#2  b1  3  3  3  0  0  5  5  5  5  0 0.4500000 0.4000000 0.3000000 0.0000000       NaN
#3  c1  1  3  0  0  2  3  3  3  3  3 0.4000000 0.4166667 0.2222222 0.3333333 0.6666667
```